# Double-slit diffraction: Reduction of intensities

Tags: double-slit-experiment, interference, diffraction, intensity

In a double-slit experiment, why do the intensities of the interference maxima decrease with the increasing diffraction angle?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of [Fourier-optics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_optics)? If yes, [the explanation is very short](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraunhofer_diffraction_equation#Slits_of_finite_width:~:text=Solution%20using%20Fourier%20transform,-The%20aperture%20function%20is).

Answer (score 0):

In a double-slit experiment is very helpful see the waves with the Fresnel-Huygens principle. In that theory, each slit is a spherical wave source. The interference pattern is the sum of the two spherical waves. Since the intensity of a spherical wave decrease with the distance traveled is obiously that for big difraction angles the intensity will tend to zero. The most brilliant point is the point were the two wave have traveled the same distances, so is in the middle between the slits. It is not trivial that the middle is the brightest point, because the less distance traveled by one wave is the point in front the slit. But you can see it with a Mathematic analysis.

$I = I_0 cos^2(ksen(\theta) d)[\frac{sin(ksen(\theta) d)}{ksen(\theta) d}]^2$

Where $\theta$ is the diffraction angle, d the distance between slits and k the number of waves.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle

Answer (score 0):

Light is  transverse wave, i.e. the oscillating electric field is at right
angles to the light direction.

So, if you direct illumination at a pair of slits, you do so with E vector in the plane
of the slits, and (on the 'dark' side of the slits) there will be no E vector
component in the direction normal to the plane of the slits, by symmetry.

That means that a cosine-squared falloff of light power is to be expected
and will be superimposed on the diffraction maxima and minima.

Also, in the usual flat-screen projection, the center of the flat screen is
closest to the slits, and an inverse square law applies, so that more distant
regions on the screen get lessened light intensity.